# Change of address after re-allocation

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, reference-wrapper

In the code below, whenever a new member is inserted to the `std::vector<int>A`, due to memory re-allocations, `std::vector<reference_wrapper<int>>B` points to a wrong address. Is it possible to make the referencing vector to track the re-allocations and store the correct address always?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> A (0,3);
    vector<reference_wrapper<int>> B;
    B.push_back ( ref(A[0]) );
    B.push_back ( ref(A[1]) );
    B.push_back ( ref(A[2]) );

    A.push_back (0);

    cout << &A[0] << endl;
    cout << &B[0].get() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the usecase for this? can't you just save the iterator instead of reference?

Comment: @cerkiewny The iterators would also get invalidated.

Comment: @cerkiewny: How would that help? Iterators are generally invalidated at least as often as references.

Comment: ok guys yes you are right, sorry my bad. the iterators will be invalidated as well.

Comment: Do you really need the address? Can't you just store the index?

Comment: You could use `list` or `deque` if you don't want the elements to move.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see is to reserve enough memory for the vector that it would not be reallocated when a new element is pushed back provided that you do not remove or insert elements in the middle of the vector.

Take into account that this statement

```
vector<int> A (0,3);
```

is wrong.

There has to be

```
vector<int> A (3,0);
```

or simply

```
vector<int> A (3);
```

You could write

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> A( 3 );
    A.reserve( 4 );

    vector<reference_wrapper<int>> B;

    B.push_back ( ref(A[0]) );
    B.push_back ( ref(A[1]) );
    B.push_back ( ref(A[2]) );

    A.push_back (0);

    cout << &A[0] << endl;
    cout << &B[0].get() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output can look like

```
0x9cbd018
0x9cbd018
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the actual usage for this pattern. So here is some possible solutions:

1. Store index rather than reference/iterator.
2. Change A to a list or deque which does not invalidate iterators other than the ones actually changed.
3. Dynamically allocated all the integers (e.g. `std::shared_ptr<int>`) and let A and B both store the (shared) pointer.